# How to get the location of a file in a variable in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt

Windows Command prompt Query:
I have a root directory "A".
There are several other sub-directories inside "A".
Now somewhere inside these directories there is a file called "setup.exe".
Now I want the complete path from A till the file.
I will need this path later in my batch file.
So I want it to be stored in some variable.
I have found ways to get the path but not able to store it to some variable.

Kindly help.

Comment: What if there are multiple files with the same name beneath the root directory `A` ?

Comment: No. In my case there is only one.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir C:\a\setup.exe /s /b') do echo %A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,it may help you.

```
for /r "C:\directory path" %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="setup.exe" set variable_to_store_path=%%~dpnxa
if defined variable_to_store_path (
echo %variable_to_store_path%
) else (
echo File not found
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let command **DIR** find `setup.exe` in directory tree and use command **FOR** to process the output of **DIR** to assign the found `setup.exe` with full path to an environment variable.

```
@echo off
set "SetupFile="
for /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir C:\a\setup.exe /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do set "SetupFile=%%#"
if "%SetupFile%" == "" (
    echo Could not find setup.exe.
) else (
    echo Found %SetupFile%
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

See also [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) to understand suppressing the error message of command **DIR** output to **STDOUT** on not finding any `setup.exe` by redirecting the error message to device **NUL** with `2>nul` with escaping redirection operator `>` with `^` to be applied on execution of command **DIR** instead of producing a syntax error because a redirection specified within *set* / *command* / *file* specification of command **FOR** is not possible.